# APK app is crashing when I use mysql Localhost

Tags: python, mysql, kivy

I just finish with designing the app interface and connect it to MySql db for send and retrieve data,
I was excited to convert it to an APK file and test it on my Android, application works fine but whenever I try to communicate with my database, app is crashing, Even I am using Try ,Except statement

at this point I guess that I am still missing something to connect in between my app on android and my localhost database on PC.

Here is my Connection Code :

```
class FifthScreen(Screen):

    users = os.environ.get('USER_NAME')
    pass_word = os.environ.get('WORDPASS')
    try:

        database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user=users, password=pass_word, database="logintest", port= "3306")
        cursor = database.cursor()

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    admin_email = "rasheed@hotmail.com"
    admin_password = "King"
    loggedin = False

    def receive_data(self, email, password):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("select email,password from logs")
            email_list = []
            for i in self.cursor.fetchall():
                email_list.append(i[0])
            if email.text in email_list and email.text != "":
                self.cursor.execute(f"select password,user_name from logs where email='{email.text}'")
                for j in self.cursor:
                    if email.text == self.admin_email and password.text == self.admin_password:
                        print("Hello Admin")
                        self.manager.current = 'Data_Table'
                    elif password.text == j[0]:
                        print("you successfully logged in")
                        self.manager.current = 'Doctors_Patients_Details'
                        self.loggedin = True
                        self.manager.get_screen('photo_page').ids.user_name.text = j[1]
                    else:
                        print("incorrect password ")
            else:
                print("incorrect email")
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            if self.database.is_connected():
                self.database.close()
                self.cursor.close()
                print("closed4")
```

Here is Requirments :

```
requirements =  python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==0.104.2,pillow, requests,android,docutils,mysql_connector,mysql-connector-python,fpdf

android.permissions = INTERNET,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

So I need some guide about what is the method or tool to connect in between my app on android and database on pc.
I am using Kivy, Python3 and mysql db, I am using local host for now and i didn't miss to give android permission in buildozer specs file.

Edit part:
I added IP Address instead of localhost, port 3306 and blocked firewall
I faced two issues:
1-  again crashing after communicate with database

```
class FifthScreen(Screen):

    users = os.environ.get('USER_NAME')
    pass_word = os.environ.get('WORDPASS')
    try:

        database = mysql.connector.connect(host="192.168.43.64", user=users, password=pass_word, database="logintest", port= "3306")
        cursor = database.cursor()




Traceback (most recent call last):
    10-25 21:19:50.841  3641  4045 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 328, in receive_data
    10-25 21:19:50.843  3641  4045 I python  :  AttributeError: 'FifthScreen' object has no attribute 'cursor' 

AttributeError: 'FifthScreen' object has no attribute 'database'
10-25 21:19:50.848  3641  4045 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

2- Black Screen after splash Screen is tacking too long around 3 to 4 minutes

```
win=Window{3e4abc u0 Splash Screen org.test.test3 EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I Added my Login code for example, The app is working on android but if i login it will crash

Comment: When you connect to `localhost`, your computer is talking to itself. If you run that code on a smart phone, it is trying to open a `mysql` database on that same smart phone.

Comment: oh that's why it's crashing, so if I add PC IP Address instead of localhost it will solve it ?

Comment: I don't think you got an answer to your last question. Not sure if you figured this out by now, but yes. You would need to point to the hostname of your computer. You will also need to ensure that there is a clean network path from your phone to the computer, meaning there is no firewall in the way or anything that would prevent communication between the two devices on the default mysql port. If you are doing this all within your home network, it will likely work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this issue, and It was Stupid mistake, but I want to share the problem because anyone new with this like me could fall to same mistake,

I created remote user in MySQL and give it password contain special character (&), for some reason you can't access to sever with special character.
That was the whole issue :)